# Entity vs taxonomy vs content type?

Tags: entities

I am setting a website up that will house multiple language schools, so I am mainly dealing with:

Individual language schools
Language courses

I set up a content type called ‘Schools’ and have fields on this that are unique to a specific school, example:

- School Name
- School Location
- Tel no and contact details
- Description of school

I then used entities for these things that are also unique to a school but there are quite a few of them, so I thought I’d be better with entities, then use inline reference entity fields on the school nodes (is this correct?):

- Types of accommodation
- Activities
- Facilities
- Image Gallery

Now I have come onto adding courses, there is generally a theme for these at the top level such as: ‘Intensive English’ then each school has various classes, so you mght have ‘Intensive English’ MORNING or ‘Intensive English’ EVENING. Now I don’t want to create taxonomies for this classes as I’ll have URLs that don’t have anything on them, I’d have a table with the various classes in it. But the whole website needs to be searchable.

My question is, what do I need to do for courses? I used entities but now can’t create a view that shows the nodes referencing the schools nodes and place it on the taxonomy parent: General English, Intensive English etc. Anyone got an pointers on what I should do and if I have set this up correctly?

I am struggling to create a view that shows a course page and then the schools that offer it, despite creating a reference to it, as in the image. Tried everything with contextual and relationships.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello,  are we talking about Drupal 7 or Drupal 8 ?

Comment: You can disable access to taxonomy paths with a module like Rabbit Hole. https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

Comment: @OlegVidenov - this is Drupal 7, sorry for not saying.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, something that is a 'descriptor' or category is best left as Taxonomy (i.e. Time > Morning/Afternoon/Evening) where they are used to enrich the meaning of data.

> Now I don’t want to create taxonomies for this classes as I’ll have URLs that don’t have anything on them

If access to taxonomy paths is a concern, you can install the [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module to disable access to it while preserving the functionality of taxonomy behind the scenes.

You can also use other modules like [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) to 'change' the way taxonomy paths behave. In this modules case, you can display a View on these paths instead of the default page callback for taxonomy. The View can be anything you'd like.

Otherwise, if you attempt to create a custom table to store this data, you will need to use the appropriate hooks in the Views API to describe the table and it's data, and how it relates - which can be a lot of work. In the end, it sounds like you'd wind up duplicating taxonomy current functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I stick with what I have now: School as content type node, courses as entities, I can't seem to create a view which shows the course page, with the schools that provide this course. I added a entity reference field to my entity that references the school node, as you can see, but I can't work out how to do a view as mentioned.

Comment: Rabbit Hole simply doesn't work, whichever setting I put it onto, if I go use an incognito browser, the page simply shows up. Strange.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure it is a term page and not already controlled by a view?

Comment: I used it on a content type. Tried each setting, it still shows.